# Application bundles testscope dependency also. am I missing something in pom configuration

Tags: maven-3, pom.xml

Is it possible to override maven dependency scope?
A test scope dependency is available at runtime and making conflict

This is my pom [here](https://ksudha1988.blogspot.com/b/post-preview?token=FuwHNlwBAAA.UZuBzuPyifSHn12mTdbI0NKJDGuN1lPgi5PbZOH3VlbbawkKfYi55gZTZ_Yzbow8UrrcaCDL1MgEwIl-5v68hw.v9v1OqTEsXyipB27nDROyw&postId=8525397577033198706&type=POST)

am I missing anything in config? or something overriding my scope? all test scope dependencies'transitive dependencies are available in runtime.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `<exclusions>` for the dependency which is conflicting as I have provided the snippet below. This will exclude usage of dependency in abc groupId which is conflicting with already added dependency by some other artifact.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>abc</groupId>
    <artifactId>abc</artifactId>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>GroupId of dependency to exclude</groupId>
            <artifactId>ArtifactId of dependency to exclude</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```